# Odoo : override "create_attendees()" method

Tags: odoo

I'm working on Odoo 8.

I added a smart button on my partner form to display the current opportunities of the partner. When i click on the button, i want to open the list of the filtered opportunities. This works, but not in a list of opportunities (should be crm_case_tree_view_oppor); it opens a list of leads (with my opportunities inside ??? > crm_case_tree_view_leads).

And so, when i click on the create button (on the top of the list), it opens the lead form and not the opportunity form.

Here's my code :

Smart button in my inherited partner form :

```
<button class="oe_inline oe_stat_button" type="action" name="%(action_current_opportunity_partner_list)d" icon="fa fa-star-o">
    <field string="Opp. en cours" name="opportunity_current_count" widget="statinfo"/>
</button>
```

And the associated action :

```
<record id="action_current_opportunity_partner_list" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="domain">[('partner_id.id', '=', active_id), ('probability', '!=', 0), ('probability', '!=', 100)]</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>
```

How can i tell Odoo to open the list of opportunities (crm.crm_case_tree_view_oppor) and after, make the button create to create an opportunity and not a lead ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a view_id on your `ir.actions.act_window` like:

```xml
<field name="view_id" ref="crm.crm_case_tree_view_oppor" />
```

Don't forget to set `crm` in your module dependencies (__openerp__.py)

For the second Problem (create) add a context to your action:

```xml
<field name="context">{'stage_type': 'opportunity', 'default_type': 'opportunity', 'default_user_id': uid, 'needaction_menu_ref': 'sale.menu_sale_quotations'}</field>
```

That one is just copied from the window action behind the Opportunities menu item.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works but in the tree, the "Create" button call the lead form, not the opportunity form. So it's not good...

Comment: @Peekaboo i've edited my answer. Sorry i've lost my mind on your first question :-)

Comment: So i added the view_id and the context to my "action_current_opportunity_partner_list" but it still doesn't work. I had already copied the code from the opportunities menu item but didn't work. So strange... :-(

Answer (score 0):

So i just replace my button with this :

```
<button class="oe_inline oe_stat_button" type="action" name="crm.crm_case_category_act_oppor11" icon="fa fa-star" context="{'search_default_partner_id': active_id}">
    <field string="Opportunités" name="opportunity_total_count" widget="statinfo"/>
</button>
```

Just change the name to "crm.crm_case_category_act_oppor11" and erase my own actions.

Works now.

The list worked before, button not the "Create" button. I haven't any explanations.